# ARCGIS Integration with Adobe flex Builder

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-flex-api, map-service

we have values ZONE,STREET,PLOT,PIN and ARCGIS MAP Server on plot Layers 67 , 68 , 69.
our Business logic as below.

1. Get Electricity or Water No from customer
2. Query Electricity or Water No from METER_MASTER and ZONE,STREET,PLOT,PIN details

   1. Apply Spatial query on Feature Class: Urban Physical Development Plot based on ZONE,STREET,PLOT Values 
      URL hqwgis04/ArcGIS/rest/services/WaterGIS/MapServer/68 
      Feature Class Field Names: ZONE_NO,STREET,PLOT 
      If this query return polygon, this is the customer location plot
3. If spatial query on Urban Physical Development Plot in step No: 3 did not return polygon feature, then
   Apply Spatial query on Feature Class: Cadastre Plot based on PIN

URL hqwgis04/ArcGIS/rest/services/WaterGIS/MapServer/67 
Feature Class Field Name: PIN 
If this query return polygon, this is the customer location plot

5 If Spatial queries on Urban Physical Development Plot,Cadastre Plot in step No 3,4 did not return polygon feature,then
 Apply Spatial query on Feature Class: "History Plot" based on PIN

URL hqwgis04/ArcGIS/rest/services/WaterGIS/MapServer/69 
Feature Class Field Name: PIN 
If this query return polygon, this is the customer location plot

1. We can't locate customer location If no polygon feature return after applying spatial queries in step No: 3,4,5

The Issue:

right now er have 4 URLs(Layers 67 , 68 , 69) for each of the above field and there is no relation between each of those

The Question is how we can Run the Query to retreive from the 4 URLs or find a relationship between them while searching and show the location View in the MAP.

Otherwise How I can Generate this 4 values to Table Database or Excel from ARCGIS MAP Server.

Please advise .

Thanks

Comment: I haven't completely understood your situation. Are you using the ArcGIS API for FLEX or not? If so, where are you stuck?